# how to give height of a parent to child in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a stack panel and it has one grid and I'd like the grid to have same height as stack panel.

I tried playing with `VerticalAlignment` stretch or height 100% nothing works

I tried setting the values programatically `OnNavigatedTo` but it doesn't have the effect

Any suggestions to resolve this are welcome

Please find the code below

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="#CFFF" Visibility="Visible" Orientation="Vertical" Name="ProgressOverlay">
    <Grid Name="Overlaygrid"">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">
            <ProgressBar 
             IsIndeterminate="True" 
             IsEnabled="True" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25” T HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Loading"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `Grid` panel always have the same size as the parent unless you specify the size. You can verify it by setting a `Background` color to your `Grid`.

Comment: What purpose does the`StackPanel` serve? It only has one child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StackPanel` takes by default the size needed by its content and shrinks to the size required, while a container control like `Grid` stretches to the full size available (e.g full page).

If you want to keep the outer `StackPanel`, you will have to set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `StackPanel`, not on the `Grid`.

But since the `Grid` is the only single content item in your outer `StackPanel`, you can remove it and move the properties `Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="#CFFF" Visibility="Visible"` to the `Grid`. Always try to keep your XAML structure as simple as possible.